# White screen for 2-3 seconds after integrating Akamai

Tags: caching, frontend, browser-cache, akamai

I have integrated Akamai caching in my production web application for which I have provided extensions (HTML, CSS..) which needs to be cached. But after integrating, on production I am getting white screen for 2-3 seconds as soon as I launch application in browser. Not sure why.

Note: If application files are being cached by browser than it does not take time to launch nor it shows white screen. But once you clear browser cache, Akamai should deliver files from its cache quickly.

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to understand why that is happening you need to leverage some sort of web development tools like Chrome DevTools. Check 
[How to Use the Timeline Tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool)  article. Capture screenshots during recording section may be especially helpful in you case.

Comment: Hi Leonid, thanks for responding. I am working on timeline tab. But is there any way to figure out which server is responding for a particular request? It could be Akamai or my own server.

Comment: Sure, check Network checkbox on Timeline tab. See this [animation](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/64-network-on-timeline) from https://umaar.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akamai have special headers you can use in requests to determine if you're getting cache hits with them or if you're flowing all the way to your site, here's a couple of links to get you started with them:

https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2015/03/31/using-akamai-pragma-headers-to-investigate-or-troubleshoot-akamai-content-delivery

https://community.akamai.com/videos/1227

There's even chrome extensions that will add the headers for you, there's one example in the second link but I prefer this one:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akamai-debug-headers/lcfphdldglgaodelggpckakfficpeefj?hl=en